# LintOption baseline error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, lint, android-studio-2.3, android-lint

I have the following error when I tried synching gradle on AndroidStudio:

```
Error:(41, 0) Could not find method baseline() for arguments [<project_path>/lint-baseline.xml] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.
<a href="openFile:<project_path>/build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Has anyone encountered this? Just as indicated in the [docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/lint-in-studio-2-3), I added the following in my build.gradle inside `android{...}`:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
}
```

My Android studio is also version 2.3. 
Is there any other step that I missed out?

**Update**:
Also tried the following, but got the same error:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
    baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
    checkAllWarnings true
    warningsAsErrors true
}
```

Comment: also add `checkAllWarnings true
        warningsAsErrors true`

Comment: I have tried it but it still shows the same error.
I have updated the question..

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only Android Studio that has to be 2.3. Android gradle plugin must also be updated 2.3.0+, and as indicated [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) and [here](https://medium.com/@a_lapshin/how-to-start-using-code-quality-tools-in-legacy-android-project-96acf7e9ca7b), gradle should be set 3.3+ for compatibility.

In my project's gradle file, I updated the dependencies to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Reference: https://medium.com/@a_lapshin/how-to-start-using-code-quality-tools-in-legacy-android-project-96acf7e9ca7b

Answer (score 0):

Put like this:(baseline file first in lintOption)

```
lintOptions {
        baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
        checkAllWarnings true
        warningsAsErrors true
        abortOnError true
    }
```

I've used this code.
check it out